# Rails - How to display all values in nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a hash like:

```
{"1"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"},
"2"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"22", "ratio"=>"45"},
"3"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"32", "ratio"=>"9"},
"4"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"42", "ratio"=>""}}
```

What I want to achieve is to get all the values of the ratio and exclude empty values something like this:

```
["121", "45", "9"]
```

Comment: .values.map{|x| x['ratio']}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash = {"1"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"},
     "2"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"22", "ratio"=>"45"},
     "3"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"32", "ratio"=>"9"},
     "4"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"42", "ratio"=>""}}



hash.values.map{|x| x['ratio']}.reject!(&:empty?)
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion and yeah, it works. Thanks for this.

Comment: Welcome brother

Answer (score 1):

```
> hsh = {"1"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"},
 "2"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"22", "ratio"=>"45"},
 "3"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"32", "ratio"=>"9"},
 "4"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"42", "ratio"=>""}}

> hsh.values
=> [{"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"}, 
    {"asset_class_id"=>"22", "ratio"=>"45"}, 
    {"asset_class_id"=>"32", "ratio"=>"9"}, 
    {"asset_class_id"=>"42", "ratio"=>""}]

> hsh.values.map{|h| h["ratio"]}
=> ["121", "45", "9", ""]

> hsh.values.map{|h| h["ratio"]}.reject{|v| v.empty? }
=> ["121", "45", "9"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the nicest code but you can start with this for one:

```
x = {"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"}
x.each do |key, value|
    if key=="ratio"
    puts value
end
end
```

Well, I've been a little late. Above solutions are better.

Answer (score 0):

below code will do trick, but this (`{a,b,c}`) is not valid ruby syntax.

```
> newarr=[] 
> a.values.each {|x| newarr << x['ratio']}
 => [{"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"}, {"asset_class_id"=>"22", "ratio"=>"45"}, {"asset_class_id"=>"32", "ratio"=>"9"}, {"asset_class_id"=>"42", "ratio"=>""}] 
> newarr
 => ["121", "45", "9", ""]
```

**UPDATE**

inf first version of question, empty string was also included. to skip it, you should do,

```
a.values.each {|x| newarr << x['ratio'] unless x['ratio'].blank? }
```

or,

```
a.values.each {|x| newarr << x['ratio'] if x['ratio'].present? }
```

but be aware that, above 2 lines are rails only solutions.

below is ordinary ruby.

```
a.values.each {|x| newarr << x['ratio'] unless x['ratio'].empty? }
```

Comment: Ooops! Thanks for catching that, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
arr = []
a.values.each {|e| arr << e["ratio"] if e["ratio"].present?}
puts arr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"1"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"12", "ratio"=>"121"},
 "2"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"22", "ratio"=>"45"},
 "3"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"32", "ratio"=>"9"},
 "4"=>{"asset_class_id"=>"42", "ratio"=>""}}
```

After you can simply call that command

> Hash[hash.to_a].values.map{|v| v[:ratio].if v[:ratio].present?}